# Heuristic argument on the position of $n$th prime

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I came up with a heuristic argument assuming the prime number theorem for the position of $n$th prime and wrote it down in my notes. The following is a picture of my notes.
[image]

It would be really helpful to get some feedback as to whether this heuristic argument is sound or flawed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the right idea, and $f(n) \sim n \log n$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem. This is discussed in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number